# EF Core - Using extension method inside Where

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, .net-core, ef-core-2.0

I have the following extension method to calculate Product's average rating.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static decimal CalculateAverageRating(this ICollection<ProductReview> productReviews)
    {
        // Calculate and return average rating

        return averageRatings;
    }
}
```

I want to use this method in an EF queryable where like this:

```
var products = _context.Products
            .Include(pr => pr.ProductReviews)
            .AsQueryable();

        if(searchParams.Rating != 0)
            products = products.Where(p => p.ProductReviews.CalculateAverageRating() == searchParams.Rating);
```

However im keep hitting the error "ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable`1[Products.Reviews.ProductReview]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Object]' of method ".

Can we use extension method in a EF Where? Please advice me on this.

Comment: not related to extension method, you pass wrong data type

Comment: @AlexNguyen means that the productreviews from products.Where cannot be used with the extension? I thought both are ICollection type

Comment: The data type of "products" is IAsyncEnumerable1 so you can not pass it into your extension method.

Comment: Also, note that the part `p.ProductReviews.CalculateAverageRating()` is inside one LINQ expression which EF will try to translate into SQL. Of course there's no CalculateAverageRating() function in SQL, so EF will decide to evaluate te `Where` client-side. That is, it will pull `products` into memory, without the filter and then apply the filter in memory.

Answer (score 0):

no problem with extension method in EF. The error is about wrong data type. So please try this way

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static decimal CalculateAverageRating(this IAsyncEnumerable<ProductReview> productReviews)
    {
        // Calculate and return average rating

        return averageRatings;
    }
}

var products = _context.Products
            .Include(pr => pr.ProductReviews)
            .AsQueryable().ToAsyncEnumerable();

        if(searchParams.Rating != 0)
            products = products.Where(p => p.ProductReviews.CalculateAverageRating() == searchParams.Rating);
```

PS : I have not checked above code

Answer (score 0):

First of all sorry for coming late to the party...

But like Gert Arnold said, this will all be done in memory.
So EF will fetch the entire products table in memory with the product reviews, this can be catastrophical for performance.

What you might want to do is (2 is the better way):

1. If you really want to keep using your extension method, project the needed proprties from the product and product reviews into a vm and then do the filtering.
2. Just use the average method that sql offers you